# How to switch between themes in mezzanine?

Tags: django, themes, mezzanine

I am exploring Djanngo-cms and Mezzanine both for content management.

With Mezzannine you can add new themes into the `INSTALLED_APPS` like this -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "flat",     # current_active theme
    #"moderna",
    #"nova",
    #"solid",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    #"mezzanine.accounts",
    #"mezzanine.mobile",
)
```

If I need to give the customer an option to switch between themes `flat` and `moderna`, how would I achieve that, is there a plugin?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on multi-tenancy](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html)? There is a `HOST_THEMES` setting which you need to use to specify a theme for a particular site. Mezzanine doesn't support dynamically changing the theme out of the box (although it is possible to do yourself).

Comment: @solarissmoke multi-tenancy is mapping different domains with same application. Can I give the user the feature to switch between themes? I am thinking in that case I need to run N application N being no.of themes and provide multi tenancy there

Comment: Not out of the box, as far as I know.